# How do I install the game ClanBomber?

Tags: installation, games

I love [this game](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/clanbomber), but when I type ClanBomber in Ubuntu Software center, it lists only [Granatier](http://www.kde.org/applications/games/granatier/). I probably need to add some repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [download](http://www.nongnu.org/clanbomber/) in game folder:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl-gfx1.2-dev
./configure
make
sudo make installl
sudo make install
```

Then run it with clanbomber2.

Answer (score 2):

Granatier is advertised as "...a clone of the classic Bomberman game, inspired by the work of the Clanbomber clone"

ClanBomber looks like it was last "compiled" in a package (.deb) for Ubuntu Dapper.  It is not recommended that you download such an old package and installing that - you could break stuff, even if it appears to work.

However, if you really must have the "original" - you will need to try one of two things.

Use the zeroinjector routine - step by step guide on the linked web-page below.  The instructions refer to v9.04 of ubuntu, so I dont know if they will work on the current supported versions of ubuntu.

If the zeroinjector routine does not work you'll need to download the source-code and compile the source code.

Download the source code from [here](http://www.nongnu.org/clanbomber/) and use standard build instructions such as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks. But what then this package http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/clanbomber stands for?

Comment: updated and clarified why you dont want to go down the dapper package route.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Clanbomber from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clanbomber/

Comment: http://pastie.org/1963327 and getting DirectFB to work is hell http://blog.mageprojects.com/2009/05/12/get-directfb-12-running-on-ubuntu-904-with-multi-app-support/. I have tried by installing directfb-bin package, but I get same error.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a `libjpeg.so` problem.

```
sudo apt-get install 0install 0install-core
```

`0install` is looking for `libjpeg.so.62`. I found it out when trying to launch Clanbomber from the command line.

In Xenial, I have `libjpeg.so.8` and `libjpeg.so.9` in 2 different locations

Output of `locate libjpeg.so`:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9.2.0
```

But as you see, there is no `libjpeg.so.62`

So I moved to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` in order to create a symlink with the existing library:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
```

Just in case, I did the same in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
```

Then I typed in the command :

```
0launch http://www.nongnu.org/clanbomber/zeroinstall/ClanBomber.xml
```

It worked for me. It should work for you.